# How to run multiple applications on RPI

Tags: raspbian, node.js, docker

I'm running a RPI zero (with raspbian as OS) and I would like to run some NodeJS applications. Therefore I have two applications: API and GUI. Both are nodeJS applications, so I would run them via `npm run start`.

But how do I run multiple applications at the same time?

I just started to use docker, but in this case (I'm using [rpio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpio) to get access to the GPIO) I cannot access the GPIOs from inside of the docker containers. So my question is if I can run both applications at the same time without using docker.

Comment: As long as the applications are not using the same GPIOs this should not be a problem.  WRT to multiple instances of node, they just need to use different ports (e.g., 80 and 8080).

Answer (score 1):

First of all it`s correct, that you cannot granting GPIO access from inside of the docker Container as i know so far.

A Possible Workaround is to adding **Parameters to the Dockerfile and to your application**:
Your Dockerfile should have an Entrypoint in the End like:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./yourBinary","-gpioNumber"]
```

After this you should able to start a Docker Container with following command (after the image build of course):

```
1. API: docker run --privileged -d YourImageName -gpio=22 <--- for example
2. GUI: docker run --privileged -d YourImageName -gpio=24 <--- for example
```

As mention in the comment is it Possible as long you are not using the same GPIO. Heres a Documentation for Docker GPIO access https://blog.alexellis.io/gpio-on-swarm/

Thats one suggestion.

**But** to answering your Question, **Yes!** you can run multiple Application without Docker.
**How?** As Example run your GUI and API application as process in a Background with the **bg** command
https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ubg.htm

**But** as above descripted as long you won`t use the same GPIO port